# Have can I create Dropdown with autocompleted based on other dropdown with json object

Tags: json, reactjs, autocomplete, dropdown

[image: List of dropdown here]
I wanna create dropdown based on the value of others Dropdown with json object

With json file format like this
[image: JSON file format]

[image]
How can I get the value Destination based on the City value?
Could you help me how to handle this value

Source code here [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-grothendieck-2h49r?file=/src/Dropdown.js)

Comment: Your codesandbox doesn't work.

Comment: it's working :)

Comment: In your `App` you have two components, which one of them are you using. Your may imported the wrong component. Instead of importing `ShowDelta`, you imported `Dropdown`.

Comment: Could you check with Dropdown.js in my component :)